# GTK+ Dock Panel like visual component

Tags: python, qt, desktop, gtk, dockpanel

I'm developing a small desktop application using python. I want it to be multi platform, and have a GUI similar (but simpler) to Eclipse. I know that the component that works just like eclipse layout are called DockPanel in Microsoft .NET.

Can someone help me out? Since eclipse is developed in GTK+ I guess I need only to discover the name of the GUI component, or maybe tell me another its name on GUI framework like Qt.

Comment: Eclipse is developed with SWT, which usually GTK+ if you are using Linux

Comment: But really, you need to clarify exactly what you are asking, since it is very unclear

Comment: sorry no, it is quite clear what rafelxy asks for, at least if you know Eclipse. And unfortunately, AFAIK, there seems to be no standard solution in GTK itself. There is only the external library GDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it on pywx, the Advanced User Interface module:
http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.aui-module.html

Answer (score 1):

In GTK+ there is a docking library called [gdl](http://developer.gnome.org/gdl/stable/gdl-main.html) which is used by Anjuta IDE for example. However, this would not be a very cooperative solution for cross-platform use. I *think* MonoDevelop built there docking library based on this, but I could be wrong about that.

I've personally used this application in a PyGTK (GTK 2.x) IDE. It worked great--I could dock multiple windows anywhere on the main layout and load/save layouts to an XML file. I have not tried it with PyGObject (GTK+ 3.x) yet.

As was pointed out, Eclipse is not written in Python/GTK so you'll want to investigate what Java/SWT library eclipse uses for docking or look into docking options with a toolkit like wxWidgets for better cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what a DockPanel is, but a class with 'Dock' in its name is 'QDockWidget'. This typically lives within a 'QMainWindow' and allows stacking and re-organization. There's an picture on http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmainwindow.html